# Vuex in vue .net core application

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vuex

I have an ASP .NET Core project with a Vue front end. This was made using:

```
dotnet new — install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*

dotnet new vue
```

This builds and runs fine but when I try and add vuex for state management I get a list of errors.

If I add vuex by running:

```
npm install --save vuex
```

and then whenever I try and add:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
```

the error list looks like:

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:5:45 
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:5:79 
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:67 
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:100 
    TS1005: '=' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:115 
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:5:73 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'infer'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:5:79 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'R'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:5:89 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'R'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:5:93 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'never'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:85 
    TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:94 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'infer'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:100 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Args'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:109 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'infer'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:115 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'R'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:120 
    TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:129 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Args'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:138 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'R'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:142 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'never'.

I have looked around but can't find anyone else having this problem. Looks like there's an issue with typescript and vuex? I am running the latest version of typescript in my application.

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "target": "es2015",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
  "strict": true,
  "types": [ "webpack-env" ],
  "strictFunctionTypes": false
},
"exclude": [
  "bin",
  "node_modules"
 ]
```

}

Is there anything else that people are using for state management in their apps? I want to make a 'user' entity available through the components. Global mixins didn't seem to be quite right so I though vuex would do it.

Thanks

Comment: can you also share tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the "npm update" command from within your project?
On the face of it, it seems your tsconfig.js file is fine.

Comment: thanks. that seems to have fixed most of it but I am still getting a couple of errors: ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:85 
    TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/vuex/types/helpers.d.ts:8:120 
    TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.

Comment: updated the typescript version and these have gone now. All seems to be working now. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are very welcome, best of luck with your project.